# Faddeev-Popov-Determinant of Polyakov Path Integral

Tags: quantum-field-theory, string-theory, path-integral, quantum-anomalies, functional-determinants

I'm currently trying to understand the paper "Quantum Geometry of bosonic Strings" by Polyakov. I think I roughly understand the X integration, but when it comes to the integration over the metric with the Faddeev-Popov-Determinant, I'm starting to have problems.
Especially I am confused by what is said on the sixth page

> "The constant A is most easily determined by matching (23) with perturbation theory for small phi and is found to be equal to $A=\frac{13}{24 \pi}$"

Formula (23) is the one that shows the form of the functional determinant. I am wondering in which way can one match formula (23) with perturbation theory?

Comment: Hi and welcome to physics.SE! It's currently unclear what exactly this question is asking. Please add further information about the context so that potential answerers will know exactly what the issue here is, that is, include the relevant definitions and equations so that we can understand your question without reading the paper by Polyakov.

Comment: Hi Sven. Welcome to Phys.SE.  Note that resource recom., which are restricted on Phys.SE. can usually not be mixed with an actual physics q., so I removed that subquestion.